# how to run roscore in docker in wsl

Tags: ros, docker

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been running ROS in a docker with the WSL 2 backend.   For example:

```
docker run -it ros:noetic-ros-base
```

When I run `roscore` in this, I cannot see the ros topics from outside the docker, i.e. `rostopic list` in WSL fails.  I have tried various ways of connecting the network to the WSL network, such as using the `--network=host` option, but to no avail.  Part of my goal is to run `gazebo` in a docker and access it from within WSL, so I need to solve this network connection.

The question is: how can I run `roscore` from inside the docker, and be able to publish / subscribe to it from outside the docker in WSL?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/363520/how-to-run-roscore-in-docker-in-wsl/) by [Morris](https://answers.ros.org/users/24538/morris/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2020-10-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found a **partial** answer to this.  The reason `--network=host` option fails has to do with how Docker relates to WSL; I believe it is in a VM.  Anyway, the host the container sees is actually the Windows host which has a different IP address than WSL.

The key to enable `roscore` to communicate is to publish the port it uses, which is `11311` by default.  Thus I can do:

```
docker run -it -p 11311:11311 ros:noetic-ros-base
```

Then doing `roscore` in the container and `rostopic list` in WSL will show the published topics.

The reason this is a **partial** answer is that it does **not** enable ROS publishing / subscribing between the container and WSL.  This is because each topic is assigned a random port to communicate on, and only port 11311 has been shared between the Docker and WSL.   I've seen a solution where you publish a particular port and require the node to use that port, but that is too clunky for my applications.

**Edit**: I think the best solution is to run Docker directly either in Windows or WSL with the `--network=host` option:

```
docker run -it --network=host ros:noetic-ros-base
```

I can run `roscore` in one container and publish / subscribe in another container.  All the containers have the same IP address, so no need to adjust `ROS_MASTER_URI`.  The only downside as far as I can tell is that, while the containers can communicate with each other, they cannot communicate with nodes in WSL.

---

Originally posted by [Morris](https://answers.ros.org/users/24538/morris/) with karma: 35 on 2020-10-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0